# How to load static data in datatable only once in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I'm adding 5 static records into the datatable in Page_load() event using a for loop like below.

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        //row["ID"] = auto increment 
                        row["demo1"] = "Class-A";
                        row["demo2"] = "12-12-2020";
                        row["demo3"] = false;
                        row["demo4"] = "someone";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                        dt.AcceptChanges();
                    }
```

I want to add this data only once when the web app starts. so that I can manipulate the data dynamically. but this Page_load() method is getting hit every time I do some operation on the data grid view or data table.

I already tried !IsPostback but it is not working. still getting all 5 records added in data table and other data is being removed automatically even after committing the changes.

Comment: The problem isn't how to load the data, it's how to load it once and cache it across requests. You'll have to load the data in the [Application_Star](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/app-startup)` handler. You can store it in a global static property or [ASP.NET's Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/moving-to-aspnet-20/caching)

Comment: Add code in the constructor instead of the load method so it gets called only once.

Answer (score 0):

We have different state management options to cache the data in .Net web application. So you can cache the data in Session state or Application state in global.asax file or save datatable into viewstate and bind gridview.